# Derivative of unspecified functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to get the derivatives of functions dependent on x and y.
What is the derivative of $h(xy)=g(x)f'(y)$ with respect to x and then with respect to y ? According to my calculations they are:
 $$\frac{dh}{dx}=f'(y)g'(x)$$
$$\frac{dh}{dy}=g(x)f''(y)$$

Am I right ?

Comment: You should write $h(x, y)$ instead of $h(xy)$. Your results are correct.

Comment: yes you are right I forgot the comma...thanks for your answer